# GetAdornerLayer returns null always for WPF usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I am getting always null for

```
_AdornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(InteractiveCanvas);
```

what might be the reason. I wanted to get `AdornerLayer` and need to add an `_AdornerCursor` over the same

I have seen some possible answers and it didnt work for me

Comment: @mybirthname how could it be ? Please read the question

Comment: Could you provide more details around the xaml and code you are using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.adornerlayer.getadornerlayer.aspx) you don't have any `AdornerLayer` in the VisualTree above your `InteractiveCanvas`. This can have quite a few reasons.

For example, it could be that your `InteractiveCanvas` isn't inside a VisualTree yet. (At least not in a visible one like a `Window` or a `Popup`.) That would be the case if you have something like this:

```
var adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(new Button());
// adornerLayer will be null every time.
```

The logic behind `AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(visual)` is very simple. It just walks up the VisualTree using `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(visual)`. If that parent is an `AdornerDecorator` or a `ScrollContentPresenter` then it returns the property `.AdornerLayer` of this parent (which more or less is guaranteed not to be null). If it gets to the root of the VisualTree and hasn't found any of that two types of visuals, it returns `null` as in your case.

So check the VisualTree of your `InteractiveCanvas` using the [WPF Tree Visualizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409789.aspx) in Visual Studio, [Mole](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1d05cb44-8686-496b-9af3-4ed3deed3596) or [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) and look out for any `AdornerDecorator` or `ScrollContentPresenter` in the parent elements. If you won't find any of them then this is exactly the reason behind your problem.

If you can't put your `InteractiveCanvas` inside a VisualTree yet, it would also be possible to manually place an `<AdornerDecorator>` element in the XAML somewhere above your `InteractiveCanvas`. This element will create a separate `AdornerLayer` which your code will find. This can of course be done in C# as well doing something like this:

```
var btn = new Button();
var ad = new AdornerDecorator();
ad.Child = btn;
var adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(btn);
// adornerLayer will now be NOT null every time.
```

Bottom line: Check the parents in the VisualTree of your `InteractiveCanvas` and you will find the answer.